# PostgreSQL error: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running into the following error after uninstalling and installing several times I just can't seem to get postgresql working. I am trying to setup the coding environment for ruby on rails 6 on windows 10. I have followed the following articles and have made it all the way to creating a user where i get the following errors.

links to how i got here

https://github.com/serivas/wsl2_rails_setup

https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#ruby-rbenv

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Error I'm getting when i type

```
sudo -u postgres createuser abc -s
```

Error Message;

```
createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like Postgres is not working?

Comment: yes i think we can both agree on that.... Any ideas why? Someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Like you, I am also trapped here .

Comment: @Lancer.Yan check out my answer to see how I solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved my problem for anyone that might be having similar issues.

- Make sure that your windows 10 is updated to be able to run WSL2
- First follow the link below to get Ruby and Rails installed.
- https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10
- Setup PostgreSQL from the link above,
- the link below also help me setup PostgreSQL;
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database

If your having trouble logging into Postgres make sure that you create a user in Postgres that allows the user to be able to CREATEDB. So if your user is JohnDoe make sure that you give permission for JohnDoe to create database.

Links to help you out with granting permission.

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33285/granting-a-user-account-permission-to-create-databases-in-postgresql

Make sure that you are starting your postgresql server.

`sudo service postgresql start`

And to Stop

`sudo service postgresql stop`

After User has rights to create the database, then you can go ahead and type in

`rake db:create`

Comment: Thank you very much for your notice. I will try the following methods later. Seems to work for me.